# Can someone explain why my program received an error of std::length_error?

Tags: c++

So I wrote a program for my homework about converting floating point numbers to scientific base 2 using the IEEE format. The tests that the professor gave us to run passed when I ran it on my computer with the program but when I got my assignment he says that the program encountered this error for all tests.

```
 WARNING-tester.py-152- /home/matthew/scratch/scientificFloating.out for the following 
 reasons:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

When I researched this error, it says that in can be due to an invalid string length but I don't know where that can be in my code because it ran fine on my computer.

Here is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int sign, mantissa, exponent, mantlen, count, zeropos;
  float number;
  unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)&number;
  string binary;

  cout << "Please enter a float: ";
  cin >> number;

  sign = *ptr >> 31;
  exponent = (*ptr &0x7f800000) >> 23;
  exponent -= 127;
  mantissa = *ptr &0x007fffff;
  mantlen = 23;
  binary = bitset<23>(mantissa).to_string();

  for (int i = 1; i <= mantlen; i++) {

    if ((binary.compare(binary.size()-i, 1, "0")) == 0) {
      count++; }
    else {
      break; } }

   zeropos = mantlen - count;
     binary.erase(binary.begin()+zeropos, binary.end());

  if (sign == 1) {
    cout << "-"; }

  if (number == 0) {
    cout << "0" << "E" << "0" << endl; }
  else {
    cout << "1." << binary << "E" << exponent << endl; }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and learn about [strict aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html).

Comment: @Rostislav: sounds like you know what the answer is. Why not go the distance and provide it? It would be a valuable contribution.

Comment: @beldaz I didn't want to fire up the debugger but your comment kinda made me :) Well, I put an answer in now, even if it's 4AM here now...

Comment: IEEE format? Would anyone care to enlighten me quickly on this?

Comment: @AshwinGupta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: @ShadowRanger ok great thanks! Never realized there was a standard on that.

Comment: I'd guess the exception would come from doing `binary.compare(binary.size() - i`, when `binary.size()` is smaller than `i`.  Another place might be if `zeropos` is out of range for the string.

Answer (score 2):

There are several source of undefined behaviour in your code.

First, you use the uninitialized variable `count`. So you need to initialized it to `0`: `count = 0`. Your compiler probably warned you about this during compilation - don't ignore warnings! Most of the time they contain valuable information about logical mistakes in your code.

Second, you alias the `float*` with an `int*`. This is a violation of the [strict aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html) rule. And while your code *might* work, it is not *guaranteed*, so your program may crash at any time and may [kill your cat even if you don't have one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/undefined-behavior-killed-my-cat).

Overall, there are many ways to improve your code apart from just fixing the problem. For example, you could replace your `binary.compare` with something more manageable, such as `if (binary[binary.size() - i] == '0')` or using `std::count_if` instead of the whole `for` loop, etc. etc. etc.

**Edit:**

Also, this is not C, you don't need to declare all your variables at the beginning of the function (furthermore, it is considered bad practice as it leads to use of uninitialized variables such as the one you experienced). Declare them at the point of first use and always initialize them, e.g. `int mantlen = 23`, or even better `constexpr int mantlen = 23`, so you could say `bitset<mantlen>` to fulfil the DRY principle.

Comment: To fix the aliasing violation I'd recommend taking out `ptr` and putting: `unsigned int u;  static_assert( sizeof u == sizeof number ); memcpy(&u, &number, sizeof u);`

Comment: Good answer, especially at 4am ;-)